# How to \nameref to a certain instance of a counter (used as pseudo-caption), use number in \nameref and add a title/description to the pseudo-caption

Tags: captions, labels

In the following **MWE**, the environment "**quoter**" is used let's say a little bit as a "pseudo"-caption: it is not a real `\caption` or `\captionof`, but still it generates a counter and displays a word such as "**Quote**" or "**Figure**" (or anything else to your liking) and a counted **number** after it.

I am just wondering how I could easily **reference** to a certain instance of such a "**quoter**"-environment, with the **number** and additionally a **title/description** of the "**Quote**" (in casu, or in other cases: "**Figure**", or anything else).

With a real `\caption` or `\captionof`, this is not all too hard. But, how do we do it for this "pseudo"-caption? A vital step is to know how to recuperate the number of a certain labeled Quote, but not reference to it according to its number (because that might change because the whole document might change). It might be good to somehow automatically `\label` a quote's **title/description**, and then through that: automatically recuperate the Quote's number.

The MWE shows how a desired end-result could look like.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%%%%% quoter environment

\newcounter{quote}

\newmdenv[
hidealllines=true,
innertopmargin=16pt,
innerbottommargin=10pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
skipabove=10pt,
skipbelow=10pt,
singleextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P) $ );
  \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) {[sharp corners] --
    ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
    ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) --
    (P|-O) --
    (O) -- cycle;
  \node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
    {\refstepcounter{quote}\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
  },
firstextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
  \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) {[sharp corners] --
    ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
    ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O) --
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) --
    (P|-O);
  \node[overlay] at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
    {\refstepcounter{quote}\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
  },
middleextra={
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (O);
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (P) -- 
    (P|-O);
  },
secondextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (O) --
    (P|-O) --
    (P);
  },
]{quoter}

%%%%% begin the beguine

\begin{document}

If you are interested in this, please see \textbf{Quote 1: Kierkegaard's quote, reproduced blindly from the internet}.

\begin{quoter}

\begin{center}

\textbf{Kierkegaard's quote, reproduced blindly from the internet}
\vspace{0.5em}
\hrule
\vspace{1em}

\end{center}

The function of prayer is not to influence God, but rather to change the nature of the one who prays.\footnote{Kierkegaard.}

\end{quoter}

\end{document}
```

*P.S.: It would be handy, of course, to have the `\nameref`, or the "pseudo"-nameref automatically (or optionally) clickable hyperlink to the actual **Quote**.*

Comment: \nameref is not standard LaTeX, but is provided by hyperref (and possibly other packages). Hyperref modifies \label to pass more information than a standard \label.

Comment: @John Kormylo Thanks for that, I'll change all mentions of the word `\nameref` into `\label` then, in the OP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to write text content to the `.aux` file

I've done this using an `\labelText` command that is setting the title and sets the label (according to user specifcations.)

Use `\nameref` then to refer to this label.

The formatting should be done outside of the textlabel, not inside.

(Since I am writing on a Tablet, I can't provide a better solution right now)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%%%%% quoter environment

\newcounter{quote}

\newmdenv[
hidealllines=true,
innertopmargin=16pt,
innerbottommargin=10pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
skipabove=10pt,
skipbelow=10pt,
settings={\refstepcounter{quote}},
singleextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P) $ );
  \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) {[sharp corners] --
    ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
    ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) --
    (P|-O) --
    (O) -- cycle;
  \node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
    {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
  },
firstextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
  \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) {[sharp corners] --
    ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
    ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O) --
    (O|-P) -- 
    (aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
    ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
    ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
    (P) --
    (P|-O);
  \node[overlay] at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
    {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
  },
middleextra={
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (O);
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (P) -- 
    (P|-O);
  },
secondextra={
  \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
  \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
    (O|-P) -- 
    (O) --
    (P|-O) --
    (P);
  },
]{quoter}




\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelText}[2]{%
#1%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
  \string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{Quote \thequote: #1}}{quoter.\number\value{quote}}{}}%
}%
}
%%%%% begin the beguine

\begin{document}

%\textbf{Quote 1: Kierkegaard's quote, reproduced blindly from the internet}.

If you are interested in this, please see \textbf{\nameref{kierkegaard}}

\begin{quoter}

\begin{center}
\textbf{\labelText{Kierkegaard's quote, reproduced blindly from the internet}{kierkegaard}}
%\textbf{Kierkegaard's quote, reproduced blindly from the internet}
\vspace{0.5em}
\hrule
\vspace{1em}

\end{center}

The function of prayer is not to influence God, but rather to change the nature of the one who prays.\footnote{Kierkegaard.}

\end{quoter}

\end{document}
```

**Update with links**

```
 \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    %%%%% quoter environment

    \newcounter{quote}

    \renewcommand{\theHquote}{quote.\thequote}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\labelText}[2]{%
      #1%
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{Quote \thequote: #1}}{quote.\theHquote}{}}%
      }%
    }
    \makeatother


    \newmdenv[
    hidealllines=true,
    innertopmargin=16pt,
    innerbottommargin=10pt,
    leftmargin=0cm,
    rightmargin=0cm,
    skipabove=10pt,
    skipbelow=10pt,
    settings={\refstepcounter{quote}},
    singleextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P) $ );
      \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) {[sharp corners] --
        ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
        ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) --
        (P|-O) --
        (O) -- cycle;
      \node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
        {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
      },
    firstextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
      \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) {[sharp corners] --
        ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
        ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O) --
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) --
        (P|-O);
      \node[overlay] at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
        {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
      },
    middleextra={
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (O);
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (P) -- 
        (P|-O);
      },
    secondextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (O) --
        (P|-O) --
        (P);
      },
    ]{quoter}


      %\string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{#1}}{mylabelcounter.\number\value{mylabelcounter}}{}}


    %%%%% begin the beguine

    \begin{document}


    If you are interested in this, please see \textbf{\nameref{kierkegaard}}

    \clearpage

    \begin{quoter} %\label{quoter}

    \begin{center}
      \textbf{\labelText{Kierkegaard's quote, reproduced blindly from the internet}{kierkegaard}}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \hrule
    \vspace{1em}

    \end{center}

    The function of prayer is not to influence God, but rather to change the nature of the one who prays.\footnote{Kierkegaard.}

    \end{quoter}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! And adding the possibility of a clickable hyperlink from the `\nameref` to the `\labelText` is easy and elegant as well?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen: See the update please. It required the correct link anchors provided, but this done now

Comment: I have now asked a new question, since I would like to make your perfect answer compatible with another code; at the new question [Macro: compatibility of 1) Auto-colorization & 2) Auto-counter-and-title-to-label](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305863/macro-compatibility-of-1-auto-colorization-2-auto-counter-and-title-to-labe).

Comment: @VincentVerheyen: Yes, but I won't address that -- `luatex` is not my favorite, actually.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - The OP's combined code suffered from the fact that the code of the `\labelText` macro wasn't sufficiently robust (paranoid?!) to deal with the possibility that the contents of the macro's first argument might get modified "on the fly" by a Lua function. I've provided an answer to the OP's follow-up query, in which I use the `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` macros in lieu of `\labelText`. If you feel like writing an alternate answer, it might be instructive to have a solution that works with a modified (more-robust?) version of `\labelText`.

Comment: @Mico: I am aware that the text written to the `.aux` file wasn't `protected`. A `\protected@write` should be enough, I am not completely errant. I am not sure I will write an alternate answer.

Comment: @Mico: In addition: There was no indication and connection to the `colouring` question by the O.P. so I could not even guess that there will be some change later on

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I fully agree. Likewise, I had no indication until quite late in the game that the OP might want to colorize strings that are parts of cross-referencing instructions.