# Macro: compatibility of 1) Auto-colorization & 2) Auto-counter-and-title-to-label

Tags: macros, hyperref, color, labels, luacode

This question is about asking to have the following 2 **"workflows"** (if you permit me to call them as such) to be able to coexist together in 1 Tex document:

---

1. Workflow **Auto-colorization** (≅ [User Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305248/67761) in OP [Automatically colourize all occurrences of certain strings (different colouring for different sets of words)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305238/automatically-colourize-all-occurrences-of-certain-strings-different-colouring):

### Workflow *Auto-colorization* MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % choose various fonts, as needed

\usepackage{xcolor}  % for "\textcolor" and "\colorlet" macros
\colorlet{BLUE}{blue}

\usepackage{lipsum}  % filler text
\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment and "\luastring" macro

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
function colorize ( buff )
   buff = string.gsub ( buff, "Candle Wisdom",       "\\textcolor{blue}{%0}" )
   return buff
end
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\colorizeOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback 
   ( "process_input_buffer" , colorize , "colorize" )}}
\newcommand\colorizeOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback 
   ( "process_input_buffer" , "colorize" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\colorizeOn} % turn Lua function on by default

\begin{document}

\chapter{All quotes which deal with "Candle Wisdom"}\label{Quotes}

\end{document}
```

---

2. Workflow **Auto-counter-and-title-to-label** (≅ [User Christian Hupfer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305489/67761) in OP [How to \nameref to a certain instance of a counter (used as pseudo-caption), use number in \nameref and add a title/description to the pseudo-caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305462/how-to-nameref-to-a-certain-instance-of-a-counter-used-as-pseudo-caption-use/305489?noredirect=1#comment741098_305489):

### Workflow *Auto-counter-and-title-to-label* MWE (compile twice)

```
 \documentclass{book}

    \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    %%%%% quoter environment

    \newcounter{quote}

    \renewcommand{\theHquote}{quote.\thequote}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\labelText}[2]{%
      #1%
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{Quote \thequote: #1}}{quote.\theHquote}{}}%
      }%
    }
    \makeatother


    \newmdenv[
    hidealllines=true,
    innertopmargin=16pt,
    innerbottommargin=10pt,
    leftmargin=0cm,
    rightmargin=0cm,
    skipabove=10pt,
    skipbelow=10pt,
    settings={\refstepcounter{quote}},
    singleextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P) $ );
      \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) {[sharp corners] --
        ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
        ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) --
        (P|-O) --
        (O) -- cycle;
      \node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
        {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
      },
    firstextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
      \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) {[sharp corners] --
        ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
        ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O) --
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) --
        (P|-O);
      \node[overlay] at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
        {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
      },
    middleextra={
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (O);
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (P) -- 
        (P|-O);
      },
    secondextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (O) --
        (P|-O) --
        (P);
      },
    ]{quoter}


      %\string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{#1}}{mylabelcounter.\number\value{mylabelcounter}}{}}

    \begin{document}


    If you are interested in this, please see \textbf{\nameref{candle}}.

    \clearpage

    \begin{quoter} %\label{quoter}

    \begin{center}
      \textbf{\labelText{The poem Candle Wisdom}{candle}}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \hrule
    \vspace{1em}

    \end{center}

    If you knew\\
    what you will know\\
    when your candle\\
    has burnt low,\\
    it would greatly\\
    ease your plight\\
    while your candle\\
    still burns bright.\footnote{Piet Hein.}

    \end{quoter}

    \end{document}
```

---

### Workflows 1 and 2 together (changed `buff, "Candle Wisdom"` to `buff, "sCandle Wisdom"`, since doesn't compile otherwise)

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % choose various fonts, as needed

\usepackage{xcolor}  % for "\textcolor" and "\colorlet" macros
\colorlet{BLUE}{blue}

\usepackage{lipsum}  % filler text
\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment and "\luastring" macro

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
function colorize ( buff )
   buff = string.gsub ( buff, "sCandle Wisdom",       "\\textcolor{blue}{%0}" )
   return buff
end
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\colorizeOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback 
   ( "process_input_buffer" , colorize , "colorize" )}}
\newcommand\colorizeOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback 
   ( "process_input_buffer" , "colorize" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\colorizeOn} % turn Lua function on by default

    \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    %%%%% quoter environment

    \newcounter{quote}

    \renewcommand{\theHquote}{quote.\thequote}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\labelText}[2]{%
      #1%
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{Quote \thequote: #1}}{quote.\theHquote}{}}%
      }%
    }
    \makeatother


    \newmdenv[
    hidealllines=true,
    innertopmargin=16pt,
    innerbottommargin=10pt,
    leftmargin=0cm,
    rightmargin=0cm,
    skipabove=10pt,
    skipbelow=10pt,
    settings={\refstepcounter{quote}},
    singleextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P) $ );
      \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) {[sharp corners] --
        ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
        ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) --
        (P|-O) --
        (O) -- cycle;
      \node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
        {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
      },
    firstextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
      \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) {[sharp corners] --
        ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
        ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O) --
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) --
        (P|-O);
      \node[overlay] at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
        {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
      },
    middleextra={
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (O);
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (P) -- 
        (P|-O);
      },
    secondextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (O) --
        (P|-O) --
        (P);
      },
    ]{quoter}

    %\string\newlabel{#2}{{1}{\thepage}{{#1}}{mylabelcounter.\number\value{mylabelcounter}}{}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{All quotes which deal with "Candle Wisdom"}\label{Quotes}

 If you are interested in this, please see \textbf{\nameref{candle}}.

    \clearpage

    \begin{quoter} %\label{quoter}

    \begin{center}
      \textbf{\labelText{The poem Candle Wisdom}{candle}}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \hrule
    \vspace{1em}

    \end{center}

    If you knew\\
    what you will know\\
    when your candle\\
    has burnt low,\\
    it would greatly\\
    ease your plight\\
    while your candle\\
    still burns bright.\footnote{Piet Hein.}

    \end{quoter}

I had to change \textbf{buff, "Candle Wisdom"} into \textbf{buff, "sCandle Wisdom"}, since it doesn't compile otherwise.

\end{document}
```

Can you notice how the `Candle Wisdom` in `\labelText{The poem Candle Wisdom}{candle}` (from the second workflow) is currently not compatible with the `Candle Wisdom` in `buff = string.gsub ( buff, "Candle Wisdom",       "\\textcolor{blue}{%0}" )` from the first workflow *(hence I had to change to `buff, "sCandle Wisdom"`)*?

Nevertheless, we would like the string `Candle Wisdom` to ALWAYS be coloured blue in the output. But, at the same time, we ***need*** to have the text string `Candle Wisdom` in `\labelText{The poem Candle Wisdom}{candle}` (since that `\labelText` will be the title of the quote, which will need to refer to the poem **Candle Wisdom**).

**Hint (but perhaps misleading, in casu):** I have been given the suggestion that a solution might be to "protect" a commands (as can be sometimes done using `\string\yourcommand`); but that was before posting this more precise question.

Comment: Should/may it be assumed that the `hyperref` package will always be loaded, or is such an assumption invalid?

Comment: @Mico Can you clarify what you mean please? I think I can answer your question by saying that some form of an automatic clickable hyperlink should be created with every reference given to a certain **quote** (in casu).

Comment: The `hyperref` package provides the macros `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink`, which are (sort of) generalizations of `\label` and `\ref`. This mechanism should offer a workable solution; I just wanted to make sure that it's OK to assume that the `hyperref` package will be loaded by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that makes use of the `\hypertarget`/`\hyperlink` machinery of the [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/) package to create cross-referencing links. The `\hypertarget` macro places the "anchor", and the `\hyperlink` macro generates a call-out (in the form of a hyperlink) to the anchor generated by `\hypertarget`. Both macros take two arguments: the first is the "anchor text" (akin to the argument of `\label` and `\ref` in "standard LaTeX"), and the second is a text string that will be typeset.

The second arguments of `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` can contain (nearly) arbitrary text -- including the string "Candle Wisdom". :-) Conversely, the string "Candle Wisdom" should *not* occur in the first arguments of `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink`.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % choose various fonts, as needed

\usepackage{xcolor}  % for "\textcolor" and "\colorlet" macros
\colorlet{BLUE}{blue}

\usepackage{lipsum}  % filler text
\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment and "\luastring" macro

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
function colorize ( buff )
   buff = string.gsub ( buff, "Candle Wisdom",       "\\textcolor{blue}{%0}" )
   return buff
end
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\colorizeOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback 
   ( "process_input_buffer" , colorize , "colorize" )}}
\newcommand\colorizeOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback 
   ( "process_input_buffer" , "colorize" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\colorizeOn} % turn Lua function on by default

    \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage[colorlinks,
                linkcolor=black  % set hyperlink color
               ]{hyperref}

    %%%%% 'quoter' environment is set up with help of 'mdframed' package
    \newcounter{quote}
    \renewcommand{\theHquote}{quote.\thequote}
    \newmdenv[
    hidealllines=true,
    innertopmargin=16pt,
    innerbottommargin=10pt,
    leftmargin=0cm,
    rightmargin=0cm,
    skipabove=10pt,
    skipbelow=10pt,
    settings={\refstepcounter{quote}},
    singleextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P) $ );
      \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) {[sharp corners] --
        ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
        ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) --
        (P|-O) --
        (O) -- cycle;
      \node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
        {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
      },
    firstextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
      \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) {[sharp corners] --
        ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
        ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O) --
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) --
        (P|-O);
      \node[overlay] at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
        {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
      },
    middleextra={
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (O);
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (P) -- 
        (P|-O);
      },
    secondextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (O) --
        (P|-O) --
        (P);
      },
    ]{quoter}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Quotes regarding ``Candle Wisdom''} \label{chap:Quotes}

If you are interested in this, please see the poem \hyperlink{ccc}{\bfseries Candle Wisdom}.

\vspace{1.5cm}\hrule\vspace{1.5cm} % for visual separation

    \begin{quoter} \label{q:CW}
    \begin{center}
    \hypertarget{ccc}{\bfseries The poem Candle Wisdom}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \hrule
    \vspace{1em}

    \obeylines
    If you knew
    what you will know
    when your candle
    has burnt low,
    it would greatly
    ease your plight
    while your candle
    still burns bright.\footnote{Piet Hein.}
    \end{quoter}

\noindent
A cross-reference to Quote~\ref{q:CW} located in Chapter~\ref{chap:Quotes}.

\lipsum[1-2]  % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, I guess to fully reproduce the original MWE's text, one should go for `please see the poem \hyperlink{ccc}{\bfseries Quote~\ref{q:CW}: The poem Candle Wisdom}.` The only dis-advantage I see is that you know have to manually type in the text for `\hyperlink`'s second argument, where-as in OP's workflow 2, that was automatically generated (from `\labelText`) from a title of a **quote**: to minimize spelling mistakes, and save time. I guess this answer can find a solution for that: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168832/using-hypertarget-caption-in-hyperlink-caption.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen - I actually see it as an advantage that the two text snippets -- the one in the anchor, the other in the hypertarget -- needn't be the same in the proposed solution. One more degree of freedom to influence what you're writing about and how it's displayed. :-)

Comment: Another proposed purpose is that one would wish to count the instances throughout the text of `Candle Wisdom` or so, but one wishes not to include the arguments of references to labels (or hyperlinks to targets). Since, they are kind of meta. Or, let's say one writes *another* macro to generate a list of the instances of `Candle Wisdom` at the end of the document (and e.g. also add hyperlinks at the entry of the list, to the pages were that entry occurs in-text): I am just fearing for other incompatibility issues, when that new macro would mess up the second argument of `\hyperlink`.

Comment: But at the same time, I can understand your point of view. I also suppose, for example, that it could be more easy for some macro's to *catch up* with the second argument if it is completely spelled out again manually. Such could e.g. be the case, in the following proposed workflow: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305237/macro-replace-all-occurrences-of-words-which-are-identical-to-content-of-label. -- But one has to acknowledge that OP asked for `Auto-counter-and-title-to-label`, meaning (even though written badly) the title should be automatically recuperated in a link to it.

Comment: To summarize, one could say that; in some case, the answer which you had already provided could be more useful; and in other cases, an extension of your answer (which could include the answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168832/using-hypertarget-caption-in-hyperlink-caption) could be more useful. Perhaps you could expand your answer to contain two answers?

Comment: Another minor glitch I have been having, is that (when I compile your code) Chapter 1 is type-set as `Quotes regarding ``Candle Wisdom''`, not as `Quotes regarding “Candle Wisdom”`. It is thus not type-set in the way as shown in your appended image.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen - Regarding your most recent querty: Which TeX distribution, which version of LuaTeX, and which version of LaTeX do you use?

Comment: **LuaTeX**, Version beta-0.79.1 (**TeX** Live 2014) (rev 4971)  (format=lualatex 2014.9.27) & **LaTeX**2e <2014/05/01>.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen - Ah, so you're on an older system that doesn't automatically set the option `Ligatures=TeX` when loading fonts. Please add this option to the option list when executing `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont`, etc. You really ought to bring your entire TeX distribution up to date, by the way.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. -- It's difficult to update large things, as internet is very expensive where I live, and connections are often interrupted.

Comment: I have added a [new answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306163/67761), heavily copying from your great work, which automatically recuperates the second argument of a `\hypertarget`, into the second argument of a `\hyperlink`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer which depends heavily on the work done in User Mico's answer, but instead; whenever a `\hyperlink` (linking to a certain `\hypertarget`) is inserted, the title of that target (the second argument of `\hypertarget`) is automatically used as a second argument for that `\hyperlink`, by adding the following excerpt of code:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldhypertarget\hypertarget
\renewcommand{\hypertarget}[2]{%
  \oldhypertarget{#1}{#2}%
    \protected@write\@mainaux{}{%
        \string\expandafter\string\gdef
          \string\csname\string\detokenize{#1}\string\endcsname{#2}%
    }%
  }
\newcommand{\myhyperlink}[1]{%
  \hyperlink{#1}{{\bfseries Quote~\ref{q:quotecounter}: \csname #1\endcsname}}%
  }
\makeatother
```

### MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % choose various fonts, as needed

\usepackage{xcolor}  % for "\textcolor" and "\colorlet" macros
\colorlet{BLUE}{blue}

\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment and "\luastring" macro

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
function colorize ( buff )
   buff = string.gsub ( buff, "Candle Wisdom",       "\\textcolor{blue}{%0}" )
   return buff
end
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\colorizeOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback 
   ( "process_input_buffer" , colorize , "colorize" )}}
\newcommand\colorizeOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback 
   ( "process_input_buffer" , "colorize" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\colorizeOn} % turn Lua function on by default

    \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage[colorlinks,
                linkcolor=black  % set hyperlink color
               ]{hyperref}

    %%%%% 'quoter' environment is set up with help of 'mdframed' package
    \newcounter{quote}
    \renewcommand{\theHquote}{quote.\thequote}
    \newmdenv[
    hidealllines=true,
    innertopmargin=16pt,
    innerbottommargin=10pt,
    leftmargin=0cm,
    rightmargin=0cm,
    skipabove=10pt,
    skipbelow=10pt,
    settings={\refstepcounter{quote}},
    singleextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P) $ );
      \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) {[sharp corners] --
        ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
        ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) --
        (P|-O) --
        (O) -- cycle;
      \node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
        {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
      },
    firstextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
      \fill[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue!30,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) {[sharp corners] --
        ([yshift=-6pt]P) -- 
        ([yshift=-6pt]O|-P) } -- cycle;
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O) --
        (O|-P) -- 
        (aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt]aux|-P) --
        ([yshift=12pt,xshift=4cm]aux|-P) --
        ([xshift=4cm]aux|-P) -- 
        (P) --
        (P|-O);
      \node[overlay] at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=3pt]aux|-P)
        {\large Quote~\thequote} ; 
      },
    middleextra={
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (O);
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (P) -- 
        (P|-O);
      },
    secondextra={
      \coordinate (aux) at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ );
      \draw[rounded corners=6pt,line width=1pt,blue,overlay]
        (O|-P) -- 
        (O) --
        (P|-O) --
        (P);
      },
    ]{quoter}

\makeatletter
\let\oldhypertarget\hypertarget
\renewcommand{\hypertarget}[2]{%
  \oldhypertarget{#1}{#2}%
    \protected@write\@mainaux{}{%
        \string\expandafter\string\gdef
          \string\csname\string\detokenize{#1}\string\endcsname{#2}%
    }%
  }
\newcommand{\myhyperlink}[1]{%
  \hyperlink{#1}{{\bfseries Quote~\ref{q:quotecounter}: \csname #1\endcsname}}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Quotes regarding ``Candle Wisdom''} \label{chap:Quotes}
If you are interested in this, please see the poem \myhyperlink{ccc} or \myhyperlink{ddd}.

\vspace{1.5cm}\hrule\vspace{1.5cm} % for visual separation

    \begin{quoter} \label{q:quotecounter}
    \begin{center}
    \hypertarget{ccc}{\bfseries The poem Candle Wisdom}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \hrule
    \vspace{1em}

    \obeylines
    If you knew
    what you will know
    when your candle
    has burnt low,
    it would greatly
    ease your plight
    while your candle
    still burns bright.\footnote{Piet Hein.}
    \end{quoter}

    \begin{quoter} \label{q:quotecounter}
    \begin{center}
    \hypertarget{ddd}{\bfseries Whether I like Candle Wisdom}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5em}
    \hrule
    \vspace{1em}

    \obeylines
    I like Candle Wisdom.\footnote{Unknown.}
    \end{quoter}

\noindent
A cross-reference to Quote~\ref{q:quotecounter} located in Chapter~\ref{chap:Quotes}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico I still have a problem with the counters there (when adding multiple quotes). Please take a look at my answer: it outputs: [...] please see the poem **Quote 2: The poem [...]** or **Quote 2: Wheter I [...]**. It should actually say: [...] **Quote 1 [...]** or **Quote 2 [...]**: do you know how to achieve that please?